# Show JSON object from method POST in PHP language

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to retrieve a JSON object from a sql query of php file.

For this I make a html code with a form, action=queryProduct.php and method post.

HTML code:

```
                  <form action="queryProduct.php" method="post">
                     <input name="codigo" type="text" placeholder="codigo">
                    <input type="submit" value="TEST">  
                  </form>
```

queryProduct.php:

```
<?php   
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] <> ''){ 

            include("functions.php"); 
            include("tools.php"); 

            $conn = Conectarse("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "dbuser", "dbpass");  

            $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];

            echo $codigo;

            $query = "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_producto WHERE codigo={$codigo}"; 

            $result = pg_query($conn, $query);  

            if (!$result) {
                echo "Error query: " . pg_last_error($conn);
            } else {
                header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
                echo json_encode($result);
            }

        echo json_encode($result);

            pg_close($conn);      

        } else{
            ?><p>La sesión no está activa, por favor ingrese <a href="login.php">aquí</a></p>
<?php   
        }?>
```

The idea is: it's make a JSON object from the query result and show the object with the browser:  `echo json_encode($result);`

Now It doesn't nothing :(

I have tested the sql query and it's working fine...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have seen this function but my query only show a register, not multiple. Is it necessary?

Comment: what are you sending over for `$codigo`? If it's **NOT** purely numeric, then your query is not working, you're introducing syntax errors. And note that pg_query returns a result HANDLE, not the data you queried for. You cannot json_encode that result handle.

Comment: Look at what http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php returns.  Use the docs young Padawan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTM: http://php.net/pg_query

> Return Values: A query result resource on success or FALSE on failure.

That `result resource` is **NOT** something you can json_encode(). You have to fetch result rows via that handle, put that into an array, and then encode that array.